# always ask for sudo password when rebooting/shutdown the system

Tags: server, sudo, shutdown, reboot, policykit

So,

I noticed that on manjaro, if there is only one user, typing `reboot` without **sudo**, will just fail and ask for the sudo password, whereas on ubuntu server, typing this doesn't ask for the sudo password and successfully reboot the system. My question is how can I make it so that when I type **reboot/shutdown/halt**, ubuntu always asks for the sudo password even if there is only one user currently logged in ? May this have to do with polkit ? If so, how can I change this ?

The reason I'm asking this, is that I want to be sure that everyone that could have physical access to my server won't be able to reboot (unless of course by unplugging the power cable which is something different lol)

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the ways that I've done this is by [masking the `systemd` targets](https://askubuntu.com/a/1385332/1222991), which prevents certain actions from being performed, regardless of who enters the command. For example, to prevent the system from being shutdown, you can do this:

```
sudo systemctl mask poweroff.target
```

Now any attempt to shutdown the system via `sudo shutdown` or `sudo systemctl shutdown` will silently fail. The same can be done with halting and reboots:

```
sudo systemctl mask runlevel0.target
sudo systemctl mask halt.target
sudo systemctl mask runlevel6.target
sudo systemctl mask reboot.target
```

<sup>**Note:** `runlevel6` is equivalent to `reboot`, and `runlevel0` is equivalent to `shutdown` and `halt`.</sup>

To undo this, these commands can be run again, but with `unmask`:

```
sudo systemctl unmask runlevel0.target
sudo systemctl unmask shutdown.target
sudo systemctl unmask halt.target
sudo systemctl unmask runlevel6.target
sudo systemctl unmask reboot.target
```

With this in mind, now you can write a script that is executable *only* for people with `sudo` access:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Determine the operation to run (mask | unmask)
op=mask

if [[ $1 = unmask ]]
then
        op=unmask
fi

## Set the targets we want to mask
declare -a arr=("runlevel0" "runlevel6" "shutdown" "reboot" "halt")

## Run the commands
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
        cmd=$( sudo systemctl $op $i.target )
        echo "$i :: $op"
done
```

<sub>**WARNING:** This code will work, but it's pretty rough. Be sure to sanity check it with a VM or somewhere "safe" before running it on a production box.</sub>

Now you can have this script run to mask the targets after booting up, and shutdown/reboot like this:

```
sudo ~./setTargetMask.sh unmask
sudo shutdown now
```

<sup>**Note:** Feel free to call the script whatever you'd like.</sup>

Comment: That’s definitely one way I couldn’t think of on my own, thank you for this, it’s a lot easier ! One thing I’ve discovered is that with a system naked (that means no desktop environment) the only way to perform maintenance is by using Sudo, whereas a system that has for example xfce installed, will not require any sudo command. I think it’s because xfce ( or whatever DE) has to install the policykit package in order to have the restart/shutdown button working without system privileges but this applies to the whole system. Correct me if I’m wrong !